# What is the best method of imputation if the data is missing at random

Tags: missing-data, data-imputation

I am investigating sex differences in treatment response. Patients are defined as "*responders*" or "*non-responders*" at 0, 6, 12 and 24 months. My problem is that there is a huge loss to follow-up in my dataset. Of all the patients with available data at six months, only ~50% have data at 24 months. I also know that the data is missing  at random because I performed drug survival analysis and assessed that females had a HR risk for discontinuation of treatment of 1.65 compared to males. The females with the "worst" outcome drop out, and because of this, it seems that as time progresses, the sex differences are becoming smaller, but this is biased.

Perhaps one way to reduce the bias imputation. For patients that discontinued treatment, we have a variable called "reasons for discontinuation" and patients can be classified as "*lack of efficacy*", "*adverse events*", "*remission*," or "*other*" (e.g., planned pregnancy). If I were to impute data of patients that were classified as lack of efficacy or adverse events as non-responders and remission as responders, the missing would be reduced from 50% to 30% (unfortunately in reasons for discontinuation, there are many missing's also and the "other" category is not used).
This still leaves me with 30% missing. Knowing that the data is missing at random (MAR), which method of imputation if any, would be appropriate here?

Comment: Aren't you saying your data is not missing completely at random (mcar) see https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/sec-idconcepts.html#sec:notation. I would use the mice library...

Comment: @seanv507 Thank you for that link. According to that book, it would be **missing at random** because the probability of missing in the outcome (treatment response) is dependent on observable information (i.e., drug survival, dwindling percentages of study patients, and percentage females). You advised me to use multiple imputation techniques. It doesn't sound easy to implement. In health research, I have often seen researchers use LCOF. Would this be appropriate for MAR?

Comment: I would expect it to be inappropriate.  Using the mice library in R makes it rather easy to "implement", do you not use R? see eg https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/workflow.html

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4785044/#:~:text=Last%20Observation%20Carried%20Forward%20(LOCF,up%20observations%20may%20be%20missing.&text=The%20combination%20of%20the%20observed,there%20were%20no%20missing%20data.

Comment: MI is widely used in health research and well supported by all major software. LOCF is usually inappropriate (but sometimes not too wrong). On the Q: I see nothing why you think the data are not MAR (MNAR), differences in drop-out based on observed covariates do not indicate that. The more usual reason would be that if you based things on the observed data (on treatment during the trial) to impute data after dropping out of a trial (and thus no longer on treatment?) when you are in fact interested in the actual (unobserved) off-treatment outcomes, you are in a MNAR situation.

Comment: @Björn After reading the definition in the link sent by Sean, I agreed that the missing data is not MNAR but MAR. However, based on your example, I am no longer sure. I am investigating patients treated with their first TNFi (tumor necrosis factor inhibitor, i.e., treatment). They drop out of my analysis if they start their second TNFi or stop TNFi. In my case, I would be using imputation to impute the data from 0 and 6 (possibly 12) months to impute data from 12 and 24 months. I am interested in data after dropping out of "my analysis" in actual (unobserved) off-treatment outcomes.

Comment: What question are you trying to answer? Do you want to know what would have happened in hypothetically these patients had stayed on the trial treatment ("hypothetical estimand")? Do you want to know what really happened to them (i.e. you want the unobserved values on whatever therapy they are on after dropping out; "treatment policy estimand")? Do you want to know the causal effect in those that do stay on the treatment ("principle stratum estimand")? Depending on the answer to that different approaches will be appropriate.

Comment: @Björn Those are great questions. My question is if the patients had stayed on treatment, what would have happened (i.e., would they be "responders" or "non-responders").

Comment: @Björn Which approach would be appropriate for my goal? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Often a multiple imputation approach can do a good job of estimating such a hypothetical estimand under some pretty plausible assumptions.